# Scaling and resolution with png command

Tags: r, plot, png

I'm a longtime R for Windows user, but exporting plots still baffles me. My usual workflow is to make the plot in the default windows device, get it to look the way I want, and then send the code to the png function to export it. The problem is that I don't know how to set the width, height, and resolution arguments to png() so that the result has exactly the same scaling as the plot on the windows device.

Here's an example. I used the plot window GUI to save the first image, just for comparison.

```
options (device = windows)
dev.new(width = 7, height = 14)  # units are inches
plot(1:10, 1:10, xlab = "Predictor", ylab = "Response", cex.axis = 1.2, cex.lab = 1.5)
legend("top", "Windows graphics device", bty = "n")
```

[image: default windows device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCL8f.png)

```
ppi <- 300
png(filename = "test3png.png", width = 7*ppi, height = 14*ppi, 
  res = ppi, type = "cairo-png")  # units are pixels
plot(1:10, 1:10, xlab = "Predictor", ylab = "Response", cex.axis = 1.2, cex.lab = 1.5)
legend("top", "png device", bty = "n")
dev.off()
```

[image: using png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgj2s.png)

I feel like I must be missing something obvious, but I've spent a lot of time over the years fiddling with this and reading threads and blog posts, and I'm still confused. Rather than list all the various things I've tried, I'm hoping someone can quickly straighten me out.

Thanks!

Edit: Ira suggests setting the width and height args for png in inches.

```
ppi <- 300
png(filename = "test3png.png", width = 7, height = 14, units = "in", res = ppi, type = "cairo-png")
plot(1:10, 1:10, xlab = "Predictor", ylab = "Response", cex.axis = 1.2, cex.lab = 1.5)
legend("top", "png device", bty = "n")
dev.off()
```

That doesn't work because changing the default resolution of 72 ppi changes the character and point size relative to the physical dimensions.

Comment: can't you just set the width and height for png in inches?

Comment: You mean like this? [edit: Sorry, I'm not sure how to add code and images to comments. See edit to my OP.]

Comment: Do you really need to use 300 ppi?  I find the default 72 ppi works well in almost all cases except when there is a huge amount of detail.

Comment: Sorry, I just saw this comment. Yes, I find that the default resolution looks pretty bad in print. It's definitely not what I would consider publication-quality. YMMV, of course, but in any case it seems like it would be useful to have a scaling "formula" that works for non-default aspect ratios and resolutions.